# How to plot ticks and numbers of y and x axes in a ggplot graph?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis

I'm plotting a graph using ggplot. Here is the exemple with the ggplot package:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
ds <- plyr::ddply(df, "gp", plyr::summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))

ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
  theme(    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 3),
            axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 5),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25,
                                     "cm"), # length of the axis ticks

  )
```

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the ticks are inside but the numbers for the y axis are terribly aligned and the ones on the X axis are overlapping the ticks.

So in the end I'd want the ticks *inside the graph* and the axis labels (the numbers) inside the ggplot graph. I've heard that we should use the margin tool, but I'm not sure how to specify margins *inside* the graph.

Edit: You can see how when using the margin function, the numbers are not aligned properly... 
[image]

Comment: This is a good question, but I have to say, doesn't this look uglier than if the tickmarks were outside the graph?

Comment: In this example yes. This is for another project! Don't worry, it can be good looking! Especially in a map!

Comment: Okay, I won't doubt you again ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe specifying `margin` within `element_text` using the `margin` function is what you are looking for?

```
ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
  theme(    axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,-.5,0,.5, unit = 'cm')),
            axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 5, margin = margin(-0.5,0,0.5,0, unit = 'cm')),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25,
                                     "cm") , # length of the axis ticks

  ) + ylim(c(min(df$y)-.5,max(df$y)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that but the numbers of the ylab are not aligned properly. See the edit in my post

Comment: right - missed that part of the question, sorry. I have edited to address it. I think all you need is to call margin again within the element_text for axis.text.y

Comment: @lewisjr2 I'd recommend attaching a picture of your result.

Comment: good point - thanks @InfiniteFlashChess. Note I also have a call to ylim to make sure your points don't cover your labels.